# Global variable does not work properly C

Tags: c, global-variables

```
int counter = 0;

int main (void)
{
   while(1)
   {
      counter++;
      wait_ms(1000);
      if(counter==5) Led_on();
      putrsUSART("\n\rUSART: "); putiUSART(counter);
   }
}
void putcUSART(u8 data)
{
  //Wait until transmitt buffer is empty
  while(! (USART1 -> SR & USART_SR_TXE));
  //Send the data
  USART1->DR = (data & 0xFF);
}

void putsUSART (u8 *data)
{

    do{
    putcUSART(*data);
    }while (*data++);
}    

void putiUSART (u32 value)
    {
        char TXBUFFER[32] = {0};
        snprintf(TXBUFFER, sizeof(TXBUFFER), "%d",value);
        putsUSART ((u8*)TXBUFFER);
    }
```

I have a problem with the code above. Its so simple that I dont understand why it doesnt work.
If I place "int counter =0" inside the main loop (before while) then the counter counters correctly.
But now he does count but dont start by 0. But for example: 509888073;
I used a ARM32Fxx processor. Could it be a configuration fault?

Comment: How do you know it does not start by `0`?

Comment: I have printed it out with usart. End the led never goes on

Comment: I would blame the USART code or any other code not included in this test example.

Comment: actually what is your problem ? your code doesn't work ? or counter does not start from 0?

Comment: I thought it maby is too long. I will add it

Comment: The code does not start at zero what i need to have. So the code does not work because it does not start at zero. The counter part works the value increments.

Comment: do you have some variables (arrays, buffers etc) defined before counter? And are you using multiple threads to access counter?

Comment: Yes there is a buffer array defined before it. The counter variable is not accesed by other threads.

Comment: while the function main() will never return, the compiler can/will raise a warning/error because the prototype for main() indicates a returned int value and there is no appropriate 'return' statement in main()

Comment: I have a hunch. Move the counter before your arrays and buffers. Does the problem go away? If so I bet you are writing past the edge of the arrays into the counter variable

Comment: the code needs a prototype for the functions: void putcUSART(u8 data), etc before the main() function. The compiler might not complain (depends on compiler version) but the resulting executable will be generated wrong

Comment: If I move the counter before the buffer and arrays the only difference is that he starts at - values. like -536166887

Comment: regarding this line: putrsUSART("\n\rUSART: "); putiUSART(counter);  The function putrsUSART() is not defined in your code.  Perhaps you meant: putsUSART()

Comment: putrs is defined in the code just not in this fragment. All the usart functions are declared in a external file

Comment: If you put a printf of counter as the first line of main() does it print 0? I guess my real quetsion is this. Have you verified the counter is actually 0 before you do absolutely anything else with it?

Comment: I did verify that it doent matter on wich point I print the value it never is zero.

Comment: Are you printing it correctly? (may sound like a dumb question)

Comment: About the only thing I can really think of is that somehow the optimizer has messed up (not likely but I guess anything is possible). What if you mark counter volatile with `volatile int counter = 0;` . With stuff like this I'd dump the generated assembly code out and see what it is doing.

Comment: Yeah i used this usart code also in other chips. and as i say if the variable is declared in the main loop it displays it correct.

Comment: Dumb question but how big is an `int` on your platform?

Comment: Can it be somewhere in the configurations?

Comment: There are ways on some compilers to change the size of an `int`. Depends on the compiler. Easiest way to find out is use printf to print `sizeof(int)` . It should print the number of bytes.

Comment: Same size as normal platforms.

Comment: It works in the the sample program Blinky. Weird enough

Comment: It could depend on what bytes precede (or come after) it in memory. Would depend on endianess. In `C` int's are compiler dependent (and they can vary based on machine architecture).

Comment: Can you humour me and printf ("%d", sizeof(int)).

Comment: The sizeof gives me 4bytes

Comment: Before I head off to bed, I'll end on this note. If counter is truly declared globally and printing out counter before you do anything else produces a non zero value then that would indicate a bug or interaction in the C startup code (or c runtime library) prior to it calling main(). The C startup code is responsible for creating the memory area for globally defined variables (and ones marked static) and is responsible for setting them to zero. If that startup code is flawed or somehow it is being excluded from your build then it could be using data that happened to be at that memory location.

Answer (score 1):

A stab in the dark is that you're using an embedded compiler and your c-startup is not initialising the bss section. This would give the results you're seeing where local function variables are initialised, but statics are not.

To test if this is true, you can include counter in main again and mark it as static and you'll likely get the same result as it being global...

```
int main( void )
{
    static int counter = 0;
    ...
```

Please show your compile + link commands. Ideally a pastebin of the disassembled exe would be good too.

Comment: You are right about the static int variable. It gives the same result as the global variable. Only I am not sure where to find the compile + link commands and pastebin where you talking about.

Comment: Okay, well your problem is the c-startup. Check you tools for any options that say -nostartfiles or -nostdlib or something equivalent. Perhaps just let us know what tools you're using. Unfortunately without knowing the tools it's impossible to pinpoint the problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the counter variable is extended some where and some other thread is using that variable while this thread in wait state. If it is working in inside the main means, this could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

just try replacing the counter name with some other variable just to test if the counter is being used accidentally by some other thread.

Comment: Already tried but i deleted all my other threads now. The only thing left is a main loop with a led and a counter. And the initialisation of the core clk and gpio